# Как сделать чтобы div'ы располагались на одной линии?

Tags: html, css

Желательно без absolute.
https://jsfiddle.net/0axs1qmo/1/

```
div с классом top-right сползает вниз.
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
.top {
  display: flex;
}
```

И все div внутри него будут горизонтально.

Comment: У флекс-дизайна пока многовато проблем с совместимостью, к сожалению. Если все посетители сайта будут исключительно с последней версией Хрома, то тогда флекс однозначно лучшее решение. А иначе с флекс дизайном лучше немного подождать.

Answer (score 1):

В стиль "left-top" добавьте "float: left;". В стиль "top" может понадобиться добавить "clear: both". И еще один момент - у вас оба div по ширине 50%, но при этом есть граница. Надо смотреть какой у вас при этом установлен "box-sizing". Скорее всего правый div будет съезжать вниз просто потому что не помещается.